# OCMock expect a class method

Tags: objective-c, unit-testing, ocmock

So I want to be able to expect a class method being called for one of my classes

```
@implementation CustomClass

+ (void)method:(NSString*)string{
    [[self class] method:string object:nil];

}

+ (void)method:(NSString *)string object:(id)object {
    //do something with string and object
}

@end
```

and I want to call `[CustomClass method:@""]` and expect `method: string:`

I've tried method swizzling but it seems like that is only useful for stubbing.

Comment: I don't really understand your question. Do you only want to call + (void)method:(NSString *)string object:(id)object from + (void)method:(NSString*)string?

Comment: @user2404543 yes, just want a sanity check for that to make sure it doesn't stray if I decide to add functionality later

Comment: Im not sure i get it.. why cant you just call [CustomClass method:string object:nil]; from + (void)method:(NSString*)string?

Comment: @user2404543 that is what i'm doing. [self class] == CustomClass

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can test that both using method swizzling or OCMock.

With method swizzling, first of all we declare the following variables in your test implementation file:

```
static NSString *passedString;
static id passedObject;
```

Then we implement a stub method(in the test class) and go with the swizzling:

```
+ (void)stub_method:(NSString *)string object:(id)object
{
    passedString = string;
    passedObject = object;
}

- (void) test__with_method_swizzling
{
    // Test preparation 
    passedString = nil;
    passedObject = [NSNull null];// Whatever object to verify that we pass nil

    Method originalMethod =
        class_getClassMethod([CustomClass class], @selector(method:object:));
    Method stubMethod =
        class_getClassMethod([self class], @selector(stub_method:object:));

    method_exchangeImplementations(originalMethod, stubMethod);

    NSString * const kFakeString = @"fake string";

    // Method to test
    [CustomClass method:kFakeString];

    // Verifications
    STAssertEquals(passedString, kFakeString, nil);
    STAssertNil(passedObject, nil);

    method_exchangeImplementations(stubMethod, originalMethod);
}
```

But we can accomplish the same with OCMock in a much simpler way:

```
- (void) test__with_OCMock
{
    // Test preparation 
    id mock = [OCMockObject mockForClass:[CustomClass class]];

    NSString * const kFakeString = @"fake string";
    [[mock expect] method:kFakeString object:nil];

    // Method to test
    [CustomClass method:kFakeString];

    // Verifications 
    [mock verify];
}
```

Comment: thank you for the examples! I was able to make the non-OCMock example work but I had to change `Method stubMethod` to `class_getInstanceMethod`. For the OCMock example, I wasn't able to get it to work. I get the `NSProxy doesNotRecognizeSelector...`. I think it's because the mock object is a mock of an instance of CustomClass instead of the class itself. calling to the class method never reaches the instance (i think)

Comment: I guess you used class_getInstanceMethod because you are declaring the stubbed method as an instance one, not a class one like I do. And about the OCMock sample, which version of OCMock are you using(mocking class methods it's possible since 2.1)? I know the mock object is a mock of a instance, but this is the way of mocking a class method with OCMock (check the docs).